# BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() hides user's clicks

Tags: android, onclicklistener, notifydatasetchanged

My app activity displays a list view populated through a custom implentation of
a BaseAdapter. Items are composed of a progressBar and a CheckBox.

The progressBars Values are updated by a background thread through the use of a Handler which calls BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged().
In this app, the user should be able to check the Checkbox.

The issue is that it seems notifyDataSetChanged() hides or dismiss the user's clicks on the CheckBox.
What happens is that the onClickListener.onClick() is called something like 1/5 times the user clicks.

At the beginning, I thought that the value set by the BaseAdapter.getView() overrided any value set by the user's clicks on the CheckBox. So I tried something like this in getView() :

```
if (checkBox.isChecked != data.isChecked(){
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    checkBox.setChecked(data.isChecked());
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(cbClickListener);
}
```

There was no change and adding a log in the onClickListener.onClick() has clearly shown that onClick is not called every time.
What should I do?

Here's the adapter code which is very classical:

```
class InputsConfAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private final Model model;
    private final inputsConfAdapterInterface handler;
    private int[] positions;

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    class CbClickListener implements CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener{

        int inputId;

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            handler.setFailSafe((byte) inputId, isChecked);
       }
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public InputsConfAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, Model model, inputsConfAdapterInterface handler) {
        super();
        InputsConfAdapter.inflater = inflater;
        this.handler = handler;
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return model.inputs.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.theIem, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.pbPosition = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbPosition);
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb);

            final CbClickListener cbClickListener = new CbClickListener();
            viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(cbClickListener);
            viewHolder.cbClickListener = new CbClickListener();

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        final CheckBox checkBox = viewHolder.checkBox;
        final ProgressBar pbPosition = viewHolder.pbPosition;
        final CbClickListener cbClickListener = viewHolder.cbClickListener;

        final Input data = model.inputs[i];

//--- progressBar
        if (positions != null)
            pbPosition.setProgress(positions[i]);

//--- checkBox
        cbClickListener.inputId = i;
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        checkBox.setChecked(data.isChecked());
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(cbClickListener);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public void serPositions(int[] positions) {
        this.positions = positions;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        public CheckBox checkBox;
        public ProgressBar pbPosition;
        CbClickListener cbClickListener;

        public ViewHolder() {

        }
    }

    public interface inputsConfAdapterInterface {
        void setFailSafe(byte inputId, boolean value);
    }
}
```

Update for @Khaled: in the fragment that receives the listView.
There's a "synchronizer":

```
  private final Synchronizer synchronizer = new Synchronizer(new Handler(), new DefaultListener() {
        @Override
        public void ValuesReceived(ValueStruct values) {
            if (getActivity() != null) {
                adapter.serPositions(values.values);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

The updater thread calls synchronizer.valuesReceived() which posts a runnable
in the Handler instanciated in the gui Thread:

```
public interface ISink {
    void ValueReceived(
        ValueStruct inputValue
    );
}


public class defaultListener implements ISink {
}


public class Synchronizer implements ISink {
    private ISink sink;
    private Handler handler;

    public Synchronizer(Handler handler, ISink sink) {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.sink = sink;
    }

    private class ValueRunnable implements Runnable {
        ValueStruct s;

        ValueRunnable(ValueStruct s) {
            this.s = new ValueStruct(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            sink.ValuesReceived(s);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void ValuesReceived(ValueStruct s) {
        handler.post(new ValueRunnable(s));
    }
}
```

Comment: does this happen when you scroll through your list ?

Comment: Nor especlially. It happens all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to solve this issue. It's not very satisfying but it works.
The idea is doing a manual update of each progressbar instead on using       notifyDataSetChanged().

In the adapater, I added an ArrayList to store the progressbars.
At the end of this if:

```
 public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        if (view == null) {
```

I added

```
bars.add(viewHolder.pbPosition);
```

In order that each progressBar know the item it is related to, at the end of

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
```

I added

```
pbPosition.setTag(i);
```

I remove the call to adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

I changed setPositions(...) to

```
public void serPositions(int[] positions) {
    for (ProgressBar bar :
            bars) {
        int index = (int) bar.getTag();
        bar.setProgress(positions[index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be clicking on list item instead of checkbox .To work around this 
make checkbox unclickable in xml and handle check click on whole item.

Comment: Well, that's just a workaround and, in fact, in real life, I also have an editText on the same iitem, so I need to identify the click on each item.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using `OnCheckedChangeListener` instead of `OnClickListener`

```
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            handler.setFailSafe((byte) inputId, isChecked);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hum, you're right, that's better to use this one. I did it but that did not change the messy behaviour. I'll change in the main post.

Comment: @Julien I think you're problem is that you use the same listener on every item, Have you tried implementing OnCheckedChangeListener in your adapter?

Comment: I use a different listener for each displayed item: `final CbClickListener cbClickListener = new CbClickListener();` The thing I did not mention is that I tested the code without the background update and it works nice.

Comment: Added to the question.